# low quality answers in older posts

Tags: discussion

I have noticed this post
[Which JSON module can I use in Python 2.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791561/python-2-5-json-module)

the answer there has 60 votes and was accepted.
answer like this would have never been accepted in the community today.

What is the course of action to this answers? should we flag them? Shouldn't it be edited with more information?

Comment: Answers are not accepted by the community.  Only the OP can do it.  Yes, you can propose an edit to the answer.

Comment: shouldn't it be flagged for low quanitly answer?

Answer (score 1):

I have edited that accepted answer a bit to make it less link-only and copied the essential parts from the other answer into it, with the proper attribution.

You're always looking for ways to keep valuable content available and up to date. If you feel an edit can help (by copying an excerpt from linked material for example) to improve the post that should be the way forward.

Only when there is no way that editing is going to add any usefulness to the post flagging or voting to close would be the correct action. If the post is considered bad or is ill-adviced consider down voting and/or commenting to warn visitors of that post.

Comment: Thanks for [editing it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261817/how-do-we-encourage-edits-to-obsolete-out-of-date-answers), instead of downvoting and ignoring an easy fix.  That's exactly the behavior that we want for these types of answers, fix them if possible.

Comment: No problem @bluefeet. I like this new experience instead of only close/down and delete voting. I might try it more often ;)